# How can I enable 2D/3D Acceleration with QEMU?

Tags: virtualization, centos7, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have a KVM Server running Virtualizor on CentOS 7.6 . When I try to enable 2d/3d acceleration I'm getting the below error message.

```
There was an error while starting the new VPS
error: Failed to create domain from /etc/libvirt/qemu/v1033.xml error: unsupported configuration: qemu does not support the accel2d setting
```

Anyway to resolve this and get acceleration working?

Answer (score 0):

I've just got this issue myself and found that "Enable Acceleration" was enabled in the "Advanced Options" tab under "Video". I also noticed that the server running the VPS Server that had this issue, was at 100% RAM usage (cache incl) so I removed the cache and the server seemed to boot up fine. If neither of those two options worked for you, let me know and I might be able to find some docs about this.

Just noticed that this question was asked 2 years ago, either way might be helpful for someone else in the future?